# Запятая после цитаты перед словом "как"

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, цитата

> «И так далее, и тому подобное», — как любил заканчивать всякое излишне
>   краткое перечисление наш завкафедрой.

Про *так* можно не рассказывать, а с *как* — это другой случай?

Comment: меня вы не перестали читать, надеюсь? Вы в погоне за изяществом фразы суть самого вопроса не обозначили. Я правильно понимаю, что с "как" для вас "другой случай" в плане **пунктуации** всей фразы?! Сразу скажу, что не вижу причин для такой постановки вопроса. Пунктуация та же самая. Или вы что-то другое имели в виду?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы как раз запятую оставила, а тире убрала, это, как Вы сказали, другой случай:

*«И так далее, и тому подобное»,  как любил заканчивать всякое излишне краткое перечисление наш завкафедрой.*

Мне не хватает контекста для ответа. Это ведь цитата - передача слов завкафедрой без изменения? (судя по тому, что там запятая внутри; если б просто фразеологическое сочетание, там бы запятой не было, а завкафедрой по-особенному произносил - как однородные члены). Но слова автора оформлены как вводное предложение, поэтому нужна запятая без тире.

Вот если б было "так" - было бы тире без запятой: «И так далее, и тому подобное» - так любил заканчивать всякое излишне краткое перечисление наш завкафедрой.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо! Контекст, собственно, весь - это концовка к совсем другой истории. Так что пунктуация в наших руках. Беру у Вас ***«И так далее и тому подобное», как любил заканчивать всякое излишне краткое перечисление наш завкафедрой.*** А просто тире нельзя? Фраза идёт отдельным абзацем.

Comment: Тире трудно оправдать: это же не вставная конструкция, а вводное предложение с указанием на источник высказывания.

Answer (score 3):

Если "как", то я бы вообще прямую речь убрал.

> Не забывай, что у меня в голове опилки, как любил говорить Винни-Пух.

Answer (score -1):

Niemand правильно привёл пример с Винни-Пухом, за счёт чего мне не придётся писать "реферат", содержащий всевозможные исключения, поэтому выражаю ему благодарность. В общем, начнём с Вашего предложения:

"И так далее, и тому подобное", — как любил заканчивать всякое излишне краткое перечисление наш завкафедрой

И сравним с примером, приведённым Niemand:

**Не забывай, что у меня в голове опилки, как любил говорить Винни-Пух**.

**В обоих случаях** предложения необходимы для передачи речи некоторых лиц. А вот разница заключается в том, что в первом примере приводилась **цитата, в точности повторяющая слова завкафедры**, а во втором — являющаяся примерной передачей чужих слов, произносимых уже **не самим лицом, а другим человеком**. Отсюда и появляются отличия при обособлении.

Comment: А между тем, пример спвершенно не в тему. Вопро, хоть и кажется мне совершенно надуманным, но он точно совсем не про это.